# Flag a comment that you have upvoted

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, flagging

Occasionally a new user will post something that needs additional clarification.  I ask for clarification and the user posts something new and then posts a comment saying something like "I've added a wireframe that should explain this now."  I upvote the comment to acknowledge that I've seen the modification and to thank the new user for improving her post.  Later, the comment is no longer relevant and conveys no useful information.  I would like to be able to flag it as obsolete, but because I have upvoted it, flagging it is no longer an option.

**Feature request: Make it possible to flag a comment that you have already upvoted.**

Comment: I could also imagine cases where someone upvotes a comment and then later has a change of heart or where someone accidentally clicks the upvote next to the wrong comment.

Comment: One way to fix this could be to allow users to remove upvotes from comments.  I seem to remember that it used to be possible to remove a comment upvote, but just not to add it back again...am I mis-remembering or has that functionality changed?

Comment: You can undo comment upvotes, but only once, and I think it locks after a few minutes like question/answer votes. If it's a long comment thread, you could also flag one of the other comments with "Other" and just explain "some of these comments are obsolete because blah" for now until the system changes (but...don't hold your breath I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally agree with you on this. It's been an issue across stack exchange for over 2 years but no resolution as yet.

[The post on Meta StackOverflow about this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it) has (at present) 137 upvotes and no downvotes, it's had bounties raised and awarded on it too but it's still not been implemented.

I suggest adding your upvote to that Meta.StackOverflow post as well and we'll keep this question open here on meta.UX too until such a time (if ever) that it's implemented. However until then there's not really much else we can do aside from draw peoples attention to that meta post to get it more upvotes and more attention.